# How to show a component randomly on every page load? (React)

Tags: reactjs

How can I show a component randomly on every page load (using React)?

For example, I have two components:

```
<ComponentOne /> and <ComponentTwo />
```

I would like to randomly show one of the components on each page load.

Should I do it in componentDidMount()?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  loadRandomComponent() {
     // return <ComponentOne /> || <ComponentTwo />
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadRandomComponent();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See if that helps

```
class ComponentThree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>ComponentThree</div>;
  }
}

class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>ComponentTwo</div>;
  }
}

class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>ComponentOne</div>;
  }
}

class Hello extends React.Component {
randomize(myArray) {
    return myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
}
  render() {
    var arr = [<ComponentOne />, <ComponentTwo />, <ComponentThree />]
    return <div>Hello {this.randomize(arr)}</div>;
  }
}
```